# Overwriting === method and how to call it

Tags: ruby

Is this a proper way to overwite the `===` method:

```
def ===(b)
    self.venue === b.venue
    print " new === !!!!"
end
```

And how do I call it on objects `a` and `b` who (as instances of the same class) both have the variable `venue`?

I tried `puts a.===(b)` but it doesn't work. (it says `private method called for #<class1:0xsdfsd...>`

Comment: Can you provide wider context? Where do you have your method defined?

Comment: Your error message is not enough. What method does it say that is private? And what class is this method all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's proper way to overwrite `===` method.

You can call this method with:

```
a === b
```

or

```
a.===(b)
```

You have this error probably because you defined `===` method as private. Define it as a public method (above `private` keyword) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The method should return a `true` or `false`, in this case you print something and the return value will always be nil. Try to change the order and use the print first.

Although you can call it using === it is much more common to use the operator in a case-statement or in the grep method.